# flextable format numerical columns blockweise

Tags: r, flextable

I want to format some columns together.
In the following example, var1 and var2 use the same format.
Is it possible to set formats for a group of columns with one
command?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(flextable)
my_tibble <- tibble(var1=round(1:5,1),var2=round(11:15,1),var3=var2/100)
my_tibble %>% flextable() -> tab
tab %>%
  set_formatter(
    var1=function(x)sprintf("%.0f",x),
    var2=function(x)sprintf("%.0f",x),
    var3=function(x)sprintf("%.2f",x)
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use one of the `colformat_*` functions:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(flextable)
my_tibble <- tibble(var1=round(1:5,1),var2=round(11:15,1),var3=var2/100)
my_tibble %>% 
  flextable() %>% 
  colformat_num(col_keys = c("var1", "var2"), digits = 0) %>% 
  colformat_num(col_keys = c("var3"), digits = 2)
```

[image]

You can read more about this here: 
https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/articles/display.html#simple-functions-for-formatting-content